# UIView not resizing in code or interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a simple UIView and adding it to my main view - I am also changing the frame however no matter what I try it doesn't resize the view - it just lumps this huge view down onto my superview.  Changing the view size in interface builder has no effect either:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
                      calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    HotelInformationViewController *vc = 
    [[HotelInformationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HotelInformationViewController" 
    bundle:nil control:control];

    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil control:(UIControl *)control
{
  if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) 
  {
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(control.frame.origin.x, control.frame.origin.y, 286, 286); //This is the size I want to view to be 286, 286 
  }
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling  `self.view.frame = CGRectMake(...)`. `frame` is the property that represents position and size of the view within its superview, and is the thing you change to move or resize a view.

(The `bounds` attribute is the internal boundaries of the view's coordinate system that the frames of the view's *subviews* exist within, and it's rarely if ever necessary to explicitly set it)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are trying to change the **bounds**, and you are supposed to change the **frame**. Bounds is rect in internal view that should be projected to the rect in superview - a **frame**. Imagine picture of size 300x300. If you have a view on the screen with frame (0,0,100,100) and you want to show the central part of that picture you should set bounds to (150,150, 100,100). As a result you will see the central part of you picture (without resizing) shown in a rect with size 100x100 in upper left corner of a superview.